# WP_User_Query Orderby Not Working

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, array, order, wp-user-query

If I use the following code, I can retrieve users in the correct order:

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 
    'role__in'    => wp_parse_list( $atts['userrole'] ),
    'meta_query' => array(
          'relation' => 'AND',
          array(
              'key' => $atts['key'],
              'value' => $atts['value'],
          ),
          array(
              'key' => $evalMonth,
              'value' => $evalTypes,
              'compare' => 'NOT IN',
          ),
     ),
     'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
     'order' => 'ASC',
) );
```

But after I add the "OR" array, it no longer orders them correctly:

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 
    'role__in'    => wp_parse_list( $atts['userrole'] ),
    'meta_query' => array(
          'relation' => 'AND',
          array(
              'key' => $atts['key'],
              'value' => $atts['value'],
          ),
          array(
              'relation' => 'OR',
              array(
                  'key' => $evalMonth,
                  'value' => $evalTypes,
                  'compare' => 'NOT IN',
              ),
              array(
                  'key' => $evalMonth,
                  'value' => $evalTypes,
                  'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
              ),
          ),
     ),
     'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
     'order' => 'ASC',
) );
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: Keep in mind that the query you wanted to run will be extremely slow/expensive. Never ask a database for what you don't want, NOT IN NOT EXISTS, etc are all super heavy tasks that involve full table scans and temporary tables getting created. If you want to bring down a database server under heavy load with the fewest queries, these kind are the best.

Comment: Also,  are you sure you can nest relations like. that in a `meta_query`?

Comment: Thank you. I will find a different way to achieve what I want then. But I do get the results I want, just not sorted properly, FYI.